# Usage of pose to describe writing

Tags: word-usage

Following sentence I read on the web

> The NYT book reviewer was repelled by the author's *pose*. The aphorisms are lazy, the facts sloppy, and the studied cool.

Can pose be used to describe writing?

Is using *author's pose* in a book where the author narrates his own experience  e.g. such as in an autobiography, acceptable English?

If I look up *pose* noun

> noun
>
> 7. a bodily attitude or posture: Her pose had a note of defiance in it.
> 8. a mental attitude or posture: a pose cultivated by the upper classes.
> 9. the act or period of posing, as for a picture.
> 10. a position or attitude assumed in posing, or exhibited by a figure in a picture, sculptural work, tableau, or the like.
> 11. a moment in which a dancer remains motionless, usually in an assumed posture.
> 12. a studied attitude; affectation:
>     His liberalism is merely a pose.

~ [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pose)

I am wondering if this is a misspelling and should read as prose

> Prose is a form of language that has no formal metrical structure. It applies a natural flow of speech, and ordinary grammatical structure rather than rhythmic structure, such as in the case of traditional poetry.
> ~ [literarydevice](http://literarydevices.net/prose/)

Comment: It is almost certainly a typo, although "the studied cool" is ungrammatical. In fact, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pose - Doesn't mention anything of the kind. I guess it could be "post" or "prose".

Comment: @Mick Maybe he wanted to say, "The studied smth* was cool."

Comment: So one should rather use author's position and not author's pose when describing his writing? Is someone writes an answer it is not acceptable and I will mark as answer.

Comment: @HotLicks I thought prose is only used with poetry or stage plays. Can one use it to describe books that aren't quoted narrative but rather storytelling?

Comment: (Though getting back to "studied cool", that whole sentence is improperly constructed.  Basically, you can't trust any of it.  Are you sure it's properly transcribed?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the whole thing is based on a misquote.

Comment: Here is the [original article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/29/business/dealbook/review-chaos-monkeys-is-a-guide-to-the-spirit-of-silicon-valley.html) and here is the [miscopied source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12003912).

Comment: @HotLicks I quoted someone who paraphrased an article. I know the NYT reviewer didn't make a mistake, I wanted to know if the paraphraser made a mistake by using the word pose incorrectly which never occurred in the original article, hence my question.

Comment: But you quoted without the parentheses, and with the sentence truncated (without indicating that using "...").  So your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference to '**studied** **cool**' makes it perfectly possible that '**pose**' is the intended word rather than '*prose*'.

'**Studied cool**' is more often referred to as an '[**air of studied cool**](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22air%20of%20studied%20cool%22)' and is relatively common in this format, and means that a person is carefully, or in a practised manner, projecting an impression of 'being cool'. **Cool** in this context meaning something like [**calmly audacious or in control, knowing what to do and how to behave**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool) 
. They are '**posing**' as a person who is cool.

The question provides several definitions of '**pose**' including

> 12. a studied attitude; affectation: *His liberalism is merely a pose*

Therefore it is possible to understand

> The NYT book reviewer was repelled by the author's pose. ...the studied cool.

as saying that the reviewer was repelled by the author's pose as a cool person. The general structure of the whole quote is poor, leading the reader to expect that, as the aphorisms are lazy and the facts are sloppy, so the 'studied' are cool.
 The sentences could be rewritten to express the same things more clearly perhaps as

> The NYT book reviewer was repelled by the author's pose, from her studied cool to her lazy aphorisms and sloppy facts.

However, note that the quotation posted in the question is @dev2's own paraphrase.
The [original NYT quote](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/29/business/dealbook/review-chaos-monkeys-is-a-guide-to-the-spirit-of-silicon-valley.html) reads:

> There is plenty not to like in Antonio García Martinez’s Silicon
>   Valley tell-all, “Chaos Monkeys: Obscene Fortune and Random Failure in
>   Silicon Valley” (Harper). An author whose biography boasts that he
>   “lives on a 40-foot sailboat on the San Francisco Bay” is not well
>   positioned to lampoon the social mores of the West Coast tech culture.
>   The book’s dedication “to all my enemies” who made the oeuvre possible
>   confirms the impression that the blizzard of score-settling that
>   follows is less than balanced. The aphorisms are sometimes lazy, the
>   facts can be sloppy, and the studied cool – all the while insisting
>   that “I am the uncoolest person you will ever meet” – can be grating.

And the [source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12003912) paraphrased in the question actually reads:

> The NYT reviewer in the OP was repelled by the author's pose ("The
>   aphorisms are sometimes lazy, the facts can be sloppy, and the studied
>   cool – all the while insisting that “I am the uncoolest person you
>   will ever meet” – can be grating."), but ultimately able to get past
>   it to the anecdotes and "directionally correct" analysis in the book

Comment: Excellent. I suggest only that you change *perfectly possible* to to something stronger. Maybe *highly likely* or maybe even *clear*.

Comment: @RichardKayser I actually changed it *from* 'highly likely' because I thought I might be asked for proof of likelihood. This is a tough crowd you know!